# Add "SortOrder" and "PageSize" Parameters(criteria) in get a category's products REST API

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api, search-criteria, sort-by-position

I need to sort the result of the category's products GET REST API by the product's position in the category. The API is like this:

**/rest/V1/categories/[category-id]/products**

And here is a sample result of the api to get the products of a category id = 280

[image]

It seems this api does not have any search, filter, sortorder or pagesize criteria.

I need to add sortOrder criteria (to sort the result based on position) and set pagesize for navigation the result.

Kindly assist with it with custom module or whatever.

Thanks.